# Upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 Failed really bad

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, upstart

I got a popup saying i had updates, and a new release. I clicked on to do the upgrade. Things went ok for a bit, then i started getting popups talking about problems .. like 10 or so, saying i should submit a bug report. Upgrade keep going, at the very end i get a segment error, and everything crashed ... I get this same error if i try apt-get -f install. Something about ubuntu-app-launch.. Now my system has problems. How can i fix this?

```
(Reading database ... 484235 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing upstart-app-launch (0.3+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package upstart-app-launch (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 139
Errors were encountered while processing:
 upstart-app-launch
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the open file searching is a line saying:

```
Package: upstart-app-launch
Status: install ok installed
Installed-Size: xx
Maintainer: xxxxxx
Architecture: xxx
Version: xxxx
Replaces: 
Provides: 
Depends: 
Description:
```

Delete all lines until the next:

```
Package:
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue running in terminal:

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
UNUSCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSCONF
update-manager -d
```

Software Updater will show up and search for the new release, after a few seconds, you will see a screen that saying:

However, Ubuntu 14.10 is available now.

Press the button Upgrade to start upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10.

The Software Updater will ask you to confirm still you want to upgrade, press Start Upgrade to begin installing Ubuntu 14.10.

Now, the Software Updater will prepare to start setting up new software channels, and after a few minutes, the software updater will notify you the details the number of packages are going to be removed, and number of packages are going to be installed, press Start upgrade to continue.

Ended the dist-upgrade, reboot your system and:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```